# Is there a practical limit to how many times Dictionaries can be embedded within other Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I reckon I can do this:

```
Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, int>> targetChapterAdjustments = new Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, int>>();
```

(create a Dictionary that has a Dictionary as its "Definition" member).

But who far can this go - is there a set limit, or a practical limit?

Could I have a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, Dictionary<bool, <Dictionary<float, Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

...for example?

I would love/hate to see how the creation of such a class would look.

### UPDATE

Okay, LineBacker talked me into it; I tried it, but this:

```
Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, Dictionary<bool, <Dictionary<float, Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int>>>>>>>>>>>> funWithDictionaries = 
    new Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int, Dictionary<bool, <Dictionary<float, Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<int>>>>>>>>>>>>();
```

...fails with multiple syntax errors.

**Edit by L.B (Sorry too large for a comment)**

> This code compiles. Enough for your case?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>();
```

Comment: There isn't really a limit. However, if you find yourself with nested dictionaries, I'd suggest you take a step back and consider if you should use classes to more explicitly say what's going on.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I also updated your answer:)

Comment: That's the most hilarious code I've ever seen - thanks! Some cats here have no sense of humor, but I'm not one of them.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to torture yourself with such a data structure?

Comment: No, I was just curious what the limitations were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no arbitrary limit enforced by C# or the CLR. The limitation you would eventually reach is the systems memory but that would apply to the creation of any objects, not just nested structures.

The design of generics is sound and will work no matter what Type parameters you provide (assuming they are valid types). Meaning any concrete type can replace the `TKey` and `TValue` portions of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. I believe the pre-compiler actually creates a class behind the scenes with the concrete types replacing their corresponding Type arguments so all you're doing is increasing the work it has to do. If you were to construct a proof you would find the practice is sound for any number of nestings (theoretically it could be infinite, of course you can't do that in practice).

Comment: The C# compiler doesn't create a class with the concrete types (as I understand it, the C++ compiler does something like you describe with its templates). The runtime JIT and/or CLR must be the things to actually make it concrete.

Comment: @TimS. I wouldn't be surprised by that. As I said I don't know exactly what happens there, that's just how it was explained to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just asking about resource limits, I think the @evanmcdonall's answer is the right one, but if you care about code design you should avoid many nested dictionaries, because they violate many OOP's good pratices, like abstraction and OCP.

Comment: It was more a theoretical question. I can't imagine it would be possible for a normal person to grok more than a couple of embedded Dictionaries without getting an uncontrollable desire to run for Congress, but was just curious.

Comment: Ok, I've imagine that was your idea. I just want make the point, because, unfortunately, I've seen many devs use a lot of nested dictionaries. Change or refactor codes like that is like a "dictionary-hell":(